# Spring data jpa method for distinct records

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

What is the best way to get distinct records with particular column name in Spring Data JPA
I used this method but it didnt fetch distinct records

```
List<ClientView>  findDistinctClientNameByCountry(String country)
```

this is the query created by JPA

```
select
    distinct client0_.col1 as col1_23_,
    client0_.CLIENT_NAME as CLIENT_N4_23_,
    client0_.col3 as col3_23_,
    client0_.col4 as col4_23_,
    client0_.col5 as col5_23_,

from
    ClientView client0_ 
where
    client0_.COUNTRY='INDIA';
```

Comment: What do you want your method to do? If you want it to return distinct client **names**, why is the return type List<ClientView>? A ClientView is not a name.

Comment: Set<ClientView>  findByCountry(String country)

Comment: 'ClientView' is POJO Class, and for using Set<> I would need to override equals() method which I can't.